# Visual Studio Shortcut key to navigate to where [return ] statement will take us?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

Like `F12` that takes us to the `definition` of something, is there anyway that, when on `return` statement I press a shortcut key and it takes me to where the value is being returned?

Comment: Only in debugging. When execution is on `return` line press F10.

Comment: You cannot know that except at runtime. What are you trying to determine? You can possibly make use of the Call Hierarchy window.

Comment: While in code editor i.e. when writing code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function's return goes to anywhere it's called from, it's not any single place.  You can find wherever a function's called from by using Find All References (Alt+F2 in my mapping, or else right click) on the function definition.

If you're in the middle of a debug session and you're inside a function, you can look up one level on the call stack to see where the function's being called from.

Comment: Yep.  Also right-click and "View Call Hierarchy", which will have a "Calls To [method]". (is this new BTW?  I don't remember that in VS2010, but I'm using it more and more - handy)

Comment: I always forget about that, as it's still not an option for VB.NET I believe (and a new feature for the C# IDE in 2012)